# failed to allocate memory via malloc_device when using SYCL USM

Tags: sycl

I am writing neural network using SYCL, but I am confused about `malloc_device` in SYCL.

```
template<typename T>
class Linear {
    private:
       T* weight;
       T* input;
       T* result;
       T* bias;
       T* dz;
       const int M;
       const int N;
       const int K;
    public:
       Linear(T* x, T* r, int m, int n, intk, queue& Q): input(x), result(r), M(m), N(n), K(k) {
           weight = malloc_device<T>(M * N, Q);
           bias = malloc_device<T>(M, Q);
           dz = malloc_device<T>(N * K, Q);
       }
    ...
```

`x = malloc_device<T>(N * K, Q)`,
`r = malloc_device<T>(M * K, Q)`

When I have multiple `Linear`s sequently, all of instances can allocate correctly for `weight` and `bias`. However, only the last `Linear` instance can allocate correctly for `dz`, other `Linear` instances failed to allocate for `dz` and got the result `0`.

Is there anyone can explain why it happened? Thanks!

Comment: Could you be running out of memory in the device?

Comment: I am sure memory is enough. Today, I just copy old files as a new solution in VS 2019, the problem is gone. However, the old solution still failed to allocate memory for `dz`, making me confused. I opened an issue https://github.com/intel/llvm/issues/3220, and it was labeled as bug.